# Translating Cartesian Coordinates from Hand frame to World Frame: ROS & Baxter Help

Tags: ros, python, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

So I'm working with the baxter robot and using the ROS workspace. The baxter has a camera attached to its arm, from which I can read x,y,z coordinates of certain object, relative to the hand frame.

Once my object is detected, I need its x,y,z coordinate, but from the robot's main frame, so i need to translate from the hand to the robot frame, and given that the robot has 6 degrees of motion, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do that. I know that I'm supposed to use DH matrices, but could someone try and explain to me how i should proceed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236817/translating-cartesian-coordinates-from-hand-frame-to-world-frame:-ros-&-baxter-help/) by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I know that I'm supposed to use DH matrices [..]

well, that is one possibility, but ..

> [..] but could someone try and explain to me how i should proceed?

I would use the TF(2) framework ([wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2)):

> tf2 is the second generation of the transform library, which lets the user keep track of multiple coordinate frames over time. tf2 maintains the relationship between coordinate frames in a tree structure buffered in time, and lets the user transform points, vectors, etc between any two coordinate frames at any desired point in time.

I think you'll be most interested in the "*lets the user transform points, vectors, etc between any two coordinate frames at any desired point in time*" bit.

TF can be a bit of a challenge to get to grips with, so I highly recommend you do the tutorials first (and try to understand them, not just copy/paste the examples), before you try to integrate it into your own code.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-13**:
So using tf echo i was able to obtain the position and rotation coordinates of the hand of my robot. but i can't seem to figure out how, using tf, i would transform coordinates from my hand to my base perspective

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-13**:
`tf_echo` is a nice command line tool, but what you really want to use is the `tf` library in your C++ or Python based node / script. Have you looked at the other tutorials?

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-13**:
yes i have, I actually figured out a way to get the transformation matrix using fromTranslationRotation()! Thank you so much!!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-14**:
See if the [tf2_ros::BufferInterface::transform(..)](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1BufferInterface.html#aab755efc61ee430fcf25bd270fc6c3a1) function already does what you want. Manually transforming poses is fine, but the utility functions exist for a reason.

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-14**:
Do yoiu know if there's an API for the BufferInterface for python? There this link(http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_ros/html/python/tf2_ros.html?highlight=bufferinterface) but somehow i can't access the buffer interface API

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-14**:
I think it's [this](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_ros/html/python/tf2_ros.html#transformlistener) but it appears the Python side is slightly under-documented. You might want to ask about that at the issue tracker.

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-14**:
I don't know much C++, But looking at the function in the c++ api, it says that it returns the transformed output. Which is a little confusing to me, since it doesn't know the input frame, only the frame you want to transform to

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-14**:
ROS msgs like `geometry_msgs/Pose` include a `header.frame_id` field. That contains what you call the *input frame* (or at least: it should contain it). Make sure you input properly setup Poses/Points/etc, and the rest should be taken care of for you.

**Comment by [laurent](https://answers.ros.org/users/27099/laurent/) on 2016-06-14**:
So should i define header.frame_id as my input frame? Sorry im at a very beginner level at coding

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-06-14**:
No: the source of your poses (ie: your object recognition node/program) should set it, and probably to the frame your camera / sensor works in.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2016-08-23**:
For anyone viewing this question at a later data looking for the exact python commands to do this transformation, I think the correct commands are covered in [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/222306/transform-a-pose-to-another-frame-with-tf2-in-python/)